# Vector of objects - editing element and optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I am newbie in cpp, so i would like to ask few questions.
So firsty my codes:

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    App app;
    app.Start();
    return 0;
}
```

App.cpp

```
void App::Start()
{
    Doc doc;
    Element TempElement;
    for (;;)
    {
        // loop which runs menu and so on
        // Adding new element to vector:

        cout << "Input data" << endl;
        cin >> temp_string;
        TempElement.Set_some_data(temp_string);
        doc.Add_item(&TempElement);
    }
}
```

Doc.cpp

```
vector <Element> MyElements;   //before any methods

void Doc::Add_item(Element *TempElement)
{
    MyElements.push_back(*TempElement); 
}
```

Element.cpp is basicly class of which objects I would like to store in vector (which is in class Doc)

It works, but i have a few questions:

1. Is this method good enought? Should I put "vector  MyElements" before any method?
2. Is there way of creating temporary element in doc object and usuing it in App?
3. I tried to make edit function for my vector, but i faild. Just to edit some data in objects. Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change

```
void Doc::Add_item(Element *TempElement)
{
    MyElements.push_back(*TempElement); 
}
```

to

```
void Doc::Add_item(Element const& tempElement)
                   //     ^^^^^^^ Use const& instead of pointer.
{
    MyElements.push_back(tempElement); 
}
```

and change the call accordingly to:

```
doc.Add_item(TempElement);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there way of making "Element TempElement" in Doc and "passing" it somehow (e.g. as a pointer) to App? If yes, how to input data to that object?

Comment: @Thermoos, I didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Okay, let's go with another problem. I would like to be able to edit object i vector from App menu. How can i do it? Should I use iterator?

Comment: @Thermoos, can you post the definition of class `App`? That will be helpful.

Comment: @Thermoos, that didn't help at all. It will be helpful to see the definition of the class, its member functions, its member data, etc. Not the implementation of `App::Start()`.

Comment: @Thermoos, I am afraid I still don't understand what you are trying to do with your program. It might be easier for you to write one class and test its functionality in a small program before adding more classes to the program.

Comment: Okay, I'll l do my best. Thanks for your help!